# C++ read/write txt file in one task -> exchanging chars

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I try to open a txt File for reading / writing in one task.
My prior target is to exchange some characters by the saved ones in an array:

```
   void Inputfile::decryptFile(string filename)
{
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
        fstream filedest(filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out);
        if(!filedest)
            cerr << "Konnte Zieldatei nicht oeffnen!\n";
        else 
            cout << endl << filename << " geoeffnet zum entschluesseln!\n";

        while(!filedest.eof())
        {
            filedest.get(ch);
            if(ch == char(this->mostcharsencrypted[i]))
            {
                filedest.put(char(this->mostchars[i]));
            }

        }
        filedest.close();
        cout << "Fertig!";
    }
}
```

mostcharsencrypted[] and mostchars[] are integer Arrays that hold the characters. I am sure that there is just 8 Bit Ansii Value in, and I check that even before this method gets called.

So if the currently read character is the one at the current array position (i: 0 - 14) then i want to exchange the character in the txt-file with the one from mostchars[].

Currently I can see that I get exactly the type of matches, but my txt file still shows the same content.

Comment: `while (!stream.eof())` is [almost always wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5). Who's teaching this crap?!

Comment: btw the explicit casts to `char` are probably unnecessary.

Comment: Best way to do this in the real world is to memory map the file - but this looks like a learning example

Comment: it's no real application, just university stuff..
anyhowy @ tomalak: found that one quite often in books and online. What method should be prefered? I did C for some years and remember that it was also typical to read until EOF-Character. The casts to char were just another idea of "why" it may not happen. Idea behind: Stream tries to write 4 bytes integer but can only write 1 byte because of .put() so I cast to char to just give him 8 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When replacing a file, usually two separate streams are used for input and
output individually.
If you need to use one stream for both input and output,
the `while` loop will be like the following:

```
while(filedest)
{
    streampos p = filedest.tellg();
    if(!filedest.get(ch)) break;
    filedest.seekp(p);
    char ch2 = (ch == char(this->mostcharsencrypted[i])) ?
        char(this->mostchars[i]) : ch;
    filedest.put(ch2);
    filedest.sync();
}
```

Comment: This comes to an endlees loop ending up in my file with:

TLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL... <some more L> nothing

and everything in one line.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot think of the reason at the moment.
For your information, the above code works on MSVC2005 and MinGW g++3.4.5
when I tested.

Comment: I just tested it with Visual Studi 2010. Maybe I have a shot on gcc 4.4 later on. But because I have not found a good working solution I am working with a temporary file and seperated input and output streams. Anyhow, some of your code gave me some hints and thoughts:)